# How to update a dependency with quicklisp?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp, asdf, hunchentoot

I have updated quicklisp to the lates version

> CL-USER> (ql:update-all-dists)
>
> 1 dist to check.
>
> You already have the latest version of "quicklisp": 2017-06-30.
>
> NIL

But this did not update the dependencies to the latest version, ex. Hunchentoot webserver is version 1.2.35, but I need 1.2.37 because of a bugfix.

> /home/pio/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/hunchentoot-1.2.35/hunchentoot.asd

How can I update the Hunchentoot to the latest release (https://github.com/edicl/hunchentoot/releases/tag/v1.2.37) with quicklisp?

Comment: AFAIK It seems that Quicklisp is updated only once a month, and the last update was on july, 1st: http://blog.quicklisp.org/2017/07/june-2017-quicklisp-dist-update-now.html You may now have the latest version of Hunchentoot available. I'd be interested in a better solution too. I don't know if there is a discussed/planned improvement.

Answer (score 3):

`Ql:quickload` will first ask ASDF for locally available systems, which happens in a [defined order](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Controlling-where-ASDF-searches-for-systems).

I usually put all Lisp libraries that I want to be found under `~/common-lisp/` which is a standard place ASDF looks into, so it just works.

If you have some other directories, you can make these directories known to ASDF.  You can for example use the file `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf`:

```
(:source-registry
  (:tree (:home "repos"))
  :inherit-configuration)
```

This will make ASDF aware of any `.asd` files under the `~/repos/` directory.

You can then use `asdf:load-system` or `ql:quickload` to load such systems (the latter will also resolve and download missing dependencies).

If quicklisp has already installed a system in a different version and ASDF happens to find that version first, you might need to `ql:uninstall` it beforehand.

Comment: If you put new Lisp libraries under `~/common-lisp/`, to make them visible from a running image you must reset the source-registry configuration with `(asdf:clear-source-registry)`, as said in [asdf documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Configuring-ASDF-to-find-your-systems.html).